# Freeze a linq IQueryable (as a ToList().AsQueryable() would do)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, odata

Is there a way to freeze an `IQueryable` so that no additional joins will be added to the query when hitting the database? For example, I could do a `.ToList()` to freeze the query, but that has performance impacts because any filtering I do is on the middle layer and I don't have any performance gains from pre-filtering on the db server?

---

**Edit for clarity:**

I have an OData service which returns an `IQueryable` that the client can filter/sort/project as needed. I just want to prevent them from pulling more data out. I could do that by doing `ToList().AsQueryable()`, but that loses the advantage of lazyLoading, and with it, the whole purpose of allowing the client to filter the request.

One option that I looked at was to set: `EnableQueryAttribute.AllowedQueryOptions` to exclude `Expand`, however even if my initial Query had been expanded, the client is still prevented from selecting those parts.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by wanting to "freeze" a query.

Comment: Any chance you can just pass in a predicate as a param and use it as a filter so you can escape the problem entirely?

Comment: If additional joins are added when you hit the Database, I suspect it is more a factor of your Linq expression.  Please post some code that illustrates the issue.

Comment: Maybe I'm the only one, but I can see where OP is coming from.  He probably wants to pass an `IQueryable` back from the data layer without incurring the cost of a `ToList()`, but ensuring that the caller can't mess up the query. If it's possible, I'd like to know.

Comment: @sstan That is exactly right. I'll edit the question with more information.

Comment: I don't know if it could help or not, but try playing with AutoMapper and its [QueryableExtensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions), what you could do is transform your returned type in to a `IQueryable` of a new mapped type. Think of it like making a View in SQL, the end user will have a harder time selecting more data out because you did not set up the mappings but they still can apply their own filters to it. Just make sure your DAL Entities are set `internal` so external users can not reference them. If that works I will turn this comment in to a answer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That is a possibility, but it's not quite the simple answer I'm looking for as it creates a bit of extra boilerplate. However, if nothing better comes along in the next few days I would accept it as an answer

Comment: You could create a new class inheriting from the specific IQueryable object that is returned in your case that hides the methods you dont want the user to use or overwrite them with empty methods. But I could imagine that this is not suitable in your use case

Comment: @T_D: I was considering something like that as well, but the methods that OP probably wants to protect himself against are not actually part of `IQueryable`.  They are extension methods.  And I don't know how you can block those.

Comment: @T_D The problem is I don't even want to block those methods, I just want them restricted. I only want further Select/Where/Order statements to be able to act on the current scope and further refine the query, but not to allow them to expand the scope of the query with further joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im assuming that you actually have an `IQueryable<T>` instead of a `IQueryable`.

If you don't want your client having access to all `IQueryable<T>` methods, don't return an `IQueryable<T>`. Since you want them to be able to only filter/sort/project, create a object witch contains an `IQueryable<T>` but only expose the desired methods, and use that:

```
public interface IDataResult<T>
{
    IDataResult<T> FilterBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

    IDataResult<TResult> ProjectTo<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> predicate);

    IDataResult<T> SortBy<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector);

    IDataResult<T> SortByDescending<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector);

    List<T> ToList();

    IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable();
}

public class DataResult<T> : IDataResult<T>
{
    private IQueryable<T> Query { get; set; }

    public DataResult(IQueryable<T> originalQuery)
    {
        this.Query = originalQuery;
    }

    public IDataResult<T> FilterBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return new DataResult<T>(this.Query.Where(predicate));
    }

    public IDataResult<T> SortBy<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector)
    {
        return new DataResult<T>(this.Query.OrderBy(keySelector));
    }

    public IDataResult<T> SortByDescending<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector)
    {
        return new DataResult<T>(this.Query.OrderByDescending(keySelector));
    }

    public IDataResult<TResult> ProjectTo<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> predicate)
    {
        return new DataResult<TResult>(this.Query.Select(predicate));
    }

    public List<T> ToList()
    {
        return this.Query.ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable()
    {
        return this.Query.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

That way you can also prevent EF and DB related dependencies creeping up on your application. Any change on `IQueryable<T>` methods will be contained within this class, instead of spread all over the place.

Comment: I haven't actually tested this because I'm not working on this project anymore, but this seems like the best mechanism, so I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I (think) tried the same and the only solution I found is using TVF in SQL Server Manager. I am assuming EF 6.1.1 and Web API. Here are some steps to take:

(1) Create a Procedure (you can add parameters to it if you like):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetArticleApiKey] @a nvarchar(max) AS
SELECT  a.*
FROM    [dbo].[Blogs] b, [dbo].[Articles] a
WHERE   b.ApiKey = @a AND b.Id = a.Blog_Id
```

If you need this in Code-First you can use a a Initalizer with `Database.SetInitializer` in your DbContext constructor.

---

(2) Download [this](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.CodeFirstStoreFunctions) nuget package. It enables Stored Procedures that are queryable. [Here](https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com/) is the project base.

---

(3) Add the following to your DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionsConvention<YourContext>("dbo"));
}
```

---

(4) Add the stored procedure to your context:

```
public ObjectResult<Article> GetArticleApiKey(string apiKey)
{
 var apikeyParameter = new ObjectParameter(ApiKeyParameter, apiKey); // Make sure to validate this, because of sql injection
 ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Article>("GetArticleApiKey", apikeyParameter);
}
```

---

(5) You can now use this function in your controller and do a pre-filtering. Afterwards all Odata queries are still possible but only on the result of the sql-procedure.

```
context.GetArticleApiKey("MyApiKey").AsQueryable();
```

---

Hope I got right what you asking for.

Comment: Yeah, that's a lot of boilerplate, pushes logic to the db server, I like @ScottChamberlain suggestion of AutoMapper better. But, I was really just hoping for something more simple.

Comment: Yeah. I am also not lucky with this solution. But I searched a lot and did not find any other solution. The idea with the automapper is good, but for me not suitable, because I needed linq to sql and not linq to entity. If you find any better, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the simplest way to do this is to turn the `IQueryable<T>` into an `Func<List<T>>`. You then don't lose the lazy aspect, but you certainly remove the ability to do further joins on the database.

This is how easy it is:

```
public static class FreezeEx
{

    public static Func<List<R>> Freeze<T, R>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Expression<Func<T, R>> projection)
    {
        return () => queryable.Select(projection).ToList();
    }

    public static Func<List<R>> Freeze<T, R>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T, R>> projection)
    {
        return () => queryable.Where(predicate).Select(projection).ToList();
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
IQueryable<int> query = ...;

Func<List<int>> frozen = query.Freeze(t => t > 10, t => t);

List<int> results = frozen.Invoke();
```

---

Here's some basic code so that this can be tested:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Test()
{
    Console.WriteLine(1);
    yield return 1;
    Console.WriteLine(2);
    yield return 2;
}
```

Now I call this:

```
IQueryable<int> query = Test().AsQueryable();

Console.WriteLine("Before Freeze");
Func<List<int>> frozen = query.Freeze(t => t > 10, t => t);
Console.WriteLine("After Freeze");

Console.WriteLine("Before Invokes");
List<int> results1 = frozen.Invoke();
List<int> results2 = frozen.Invoke();
Console.WriteLine("After Invokes");
```

On the console I get this:

```
Before Freeze
After Freeze
Before Invokes
1
2
1
2
After Invokes
```

You can see it is lazy and that it only runs when invoked.

Comment: Yes, it is lazy, but whenever you do run the query it is still the full scope that gets run. e.g. if I just want one field of one record, the full query is still sent to the db rather than trimming down the select statement.

Comment: @JacobEggers - Are you saying that you want to be able to filter (`.Where`) still, but not join?

Comment: @JacobEggers - I've made a change that is now more flexible for you.

Comment: Yes, but the query gets run when you freeze the queryable which is overhead that I was trying to avoid. However, I've moved on to other projects, so I don't need a solution right now.

Comment: @JacobEggers - No, the query doesn't get run when you freeze. It runs only when you call `.Invoke()`.

Comment: @JacobEggers - Also, Stack Overflow's primary purpose is to make a repository of quality programming questions and answers for future browsers, so even if you've moved on the question still needs to be made a good as possible.

Comment: The problem is that I can't test if it solves my problem because I am not working on that project anymore. The purpose was to add a layer of security on top of an OAuth library, while still maintaining the benefits of using the library. I don't know if it'll work with the library and so can't judge the quality of the answer because I'm not working on it anymore.

Comment: @JacobEggers - I've added test code that you could run in a console app. It shows the desired behaviour.