# Filtering child collection in DbCotext<Entity> for authorizaton

Tags: entity-framework-6, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have an application where we have elaborate authorization process. However in a method that returns IQueryable, we do not have control on which entities in child collection will be returned.

Here is an example:

```
public class Parent{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

public class Child {
    .... details of child class
}

public MyContext : DbContext{
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents;
    public DbSet<Child> Children;
}
```

Now we have different level permissions on the parent and child items and the user with read permission on parent may not have same permission on all child items in the parent. However I have an OData Web API controller written on top of this model which has a Get method on the Parent class with IQueryable as return type and EnableQuery attribute.

```
public class ParentController : ODataController{
    private readonly MyContext _db = new MyContext();
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Parent> Get{
        return _db.Parents;
    }
    .... other methods
}
```

I have no control on what query the end user will send and if user asks for children, the DBSet will return all the children irrespective of the access permission.

Is there any way I can filter the Children property of the Parent class?

Answer (score 1):

The end user can only use a `$expand` query to get all children. Therefore he can only query again associated entities. However sometimes you need to filter more data. Then you have to options:

1. (The complex one) Create a View or Stored Procedure with tvf. [See this answer for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770017/freeze-a-linq-iqueryable-as-a-tolist-asqueryable-would-do/30774172#30774172)
2. (The easy one) Use a dynamic filter for soft delete flags. You can use this if you just want to filter data that has a flag like `IsDeleted`. Than you can include [this](https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters) extension and enable it like this:

   `modelBuilder.Filter("IsDeleted", (ISoftDelete d) => d.IsDeleted, false);`

This will only show the datasets that do not have the IsDeleted flag set to true.

Comment: Thanks. The dynamic filter solution looks promising. My worry was not as much on how the $expand behaves but more on not having control on the predicate coming with $expand. If I query on the parent with eager load on children, will the filter work on that eager loaded children?

Comment: Yes, if it implements the interface `ISoftDelete`.